# iOS presentViewController Delegates Returning Black Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, presentviewcontroller

I have created two views within my project. I want to be able to click a button on my main view and the other view (ChooseCar) will pop up allowing the user to pick something then it will reopen the old view (ViewController) with the information entered. I have done the code for it but for some reason when I click the button the screen just goes black with nothing happening, i'm pretty sure it's something very simple I just can't get my head around it.

I will attach the code for the views below, thanks.

**ViewController.h**

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//
//  Created by Curtis Boylan on 24/11/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ChooseCar.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ChooseCarDelegate>
- (IBAction)chooselocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *wherelocation;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//
//  Created by Curtis Boylan on 24/11/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
- (IBAction)chooselocation {
    ChooseCar *acController = [[ChooseCar alloc] init];
   // acController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];}

- (void)addItemViewController:(ChooseCar *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item
{
    NSLog(@"This was returned from ChooseCar %@",item);
}

@end
```

**ChooseCar.h**

```
//
//  ChooseCar.h
//
//  Created by Curtis Boylan on 24/11/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ChooseCar;

@protocol ChooseCarDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)addItemViewController:(ChooseCar *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item;
@end

@interface ChooseCar : UIViewController

@end
```

**ChooseCar.m**

```
//
//  ChooseCar.m
//
//  Created by Curtis Boylan on 24/11/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ChooseCar.h"

@interface ChooseCar ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ChooseCarDelegate> delegate;
@end

@implementation ChooseCar

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *itemToPassBack = @"Pass this value back to ViewControllerA";
    [self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishEnteringItem:itemToPassBack];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: I don't see where you dismiss the presented VC.  Shouldn't you do that in delegate method?

Comment: Just tried that, still giving me a black screen

Comment: have you used storyboard or xib to create the `ChooseCar` ViewController ?

Comment: I am using storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easy to do:

1)I believe your `ChooseCar` vc is created in `storyboard`.
if yes, you should set the `Storyboard ID` like this:

[image: set storyboard id]

2)In your `ViewController.m`, update your `chooselocation` method to this:

```
- (IBAction)chooselocation {
//ChooseCar *acController = [[ChooseCar alloc] init];

UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];


ChooseCar *acController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChooseCar"];

[self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to pass a value by delegate:

at the base of my give.

1）cut this code `@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ChooseCarDelegate> delegate;` from your `ChooseCar.m` to `ChooseCar.h` , make sure the `ChooseCar.h` like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ChooseCar;

@protocol ChooseCarDelegate <NSObject>


- (void)addItemViewController:(ChooseCar *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item;

@end


@interface ChooseCar : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ChooseCarDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

2) In the `ViewController.m`, you should abide the `protocal`, and set `caController`'s  delegate.

```
#import "ChooseCar.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <ChooseCarDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
- (IBAction)chooselocation {
    //ChooseCar *acController = [[ChooseCar alloc] init];

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];


    ChooseCar *acController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChooseCar"];

    acController.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)addItemViewController:(ChooseCar *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item
{
    NSLog(@"This was returned from ChooseCar %@",item);
}

@end
```

3)If you want to pass the value, you should take this code to your action:

```
NSString *itemToPassBack = @"Pass this value back to ViewControllerA";
[self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishEnteringItem:itemToPassBack];
```

Comment: This works and opens up the choosecar view but does not take me back to the view controller and pass the value

Comment: @Curtis Boylan I have EDIT my answer, you look that.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with the following:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ChooseCar.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ChooseCarDelegate>
- (IBAction)chooselocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *wherelocation;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    ChooseCar *acController;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
- (IBAction)chooselocation {

    acController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChooseCar"];
    acController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)addItemViewController:(ChooseCar *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item
{
    [acController dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"This was returned from ChooseCar %@",item);
}

@end
```

Also set the storyboard id in storyboard. For more details see the attached screenshot:

[image]

**ChooseCar.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ChooseCar;

@protocol ChooseCarDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)addItemViewController:(ChooseCar *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item;
@end

@interface ChooseCar : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ChooseCarDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

**ChooseCar.m**

```
#import "ChooseCar.h"

@interface ChooseCar ()
@end

@implementation ChooseCar

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

//    NSString *itemToPassBack = @"Pass this value back to ViewControllerA";
//    [self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishEnteringItem:itemToPassBack];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)backButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSString *itemToPassBack = @"Pass this value back to ViewControllerA";
   [self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishEnteringItem:itemToPassBack];
}

/*
 #pragma mark - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
 // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */

@end
```

Comment: Yes that works great but it opens the ChooseCar view and does not go back to the ViewController. It also does not return the item from ChooseCar. Any solution to make this work?

Comment: When do you want to back? On button click ?

Comment: Yeah on the button click I want it to take you back to the other view and pass back the item value.

Comment: I have updated my code. It will work for you to go back.